# Is it allowed to ask LilyPond questions here

Tags: discussion, scope

[LilyPond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LilyPond) is a language for typesetting music. It's not actually LaTeX and requires knowledge of music notation. But it is integrated with LaTeX and has a lot of in common with it.

Is it allowed to ask the questions about it here? Is there a chance to get an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer has to be no really. It seems to be stretching the "related typesetting systems" too far. There is a [lilypond tag on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lilypond)

Comment: We have 24 questions tagged with [tag:lillypond].

Comment: @MartinSchröder can you fix that link otherwise it's a bit confusing: one l)  True but looking at the first few of them they all mention latex so they are about the interaction between lilypond and tex which is on topic, and we always tolerate the occasional OT question anyway. so 24 sounds about right.

Comment: Sorry, that comment is fixed. Here's the correct one: [tag:lilypond].

Answer (score 16):

Lilypond originally was developed using LaTeX, but the current version does *not* use TeX at all to produce its output of graphical music scores. So questions about Lilypond's syntax (or the Scheme syntax used to modify it) are off topic.

As with any program that produces graphical output (Inkscape, Gimp, Photoshop), you can include the output graphic files into a LaTeX document using `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package. From the TeX engine's perspective these files are just big boxes to put on the page; it doesn't matter whether it's music or pictures inside. Questions about doing this are only on topic if they relate to how TeX gets and arranges that box on the page.

The Lilypond documentation gives the impression that the program is closely integrated with LaTeX because there is a `lilypond-book` program that includes Lilypond images within a LaTeX file. This program is basically just an automated way of processing each separate image with Lilypond and then using `\includegraphics`. (In fact in many cases it is, in my opinion, simpler just to do it that way manually.)

As an active Lilypond user, I would encourage users to please start posting and answering Lilypond questions on StackOverflow with the [`lilypond`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) tag. The lilypond-user mailing list is currently the main place where lilypond questions are discussed, but the Q/A format and resulting knowledge base of SO would in my opinion be more helpful to the Lilypond community in the long run.

Comment: Still, questions in which `lilypond-book` plays a significant role are IMHO on-topic, similarly as are certain R questions, for instance.

Comment: @yo' Yes, I think so. We need to look into the workings of `lilypond-book`, as that program itself might be considered a TeX-based typesetting system, in which questions about how it works could not just be solved with non-Lilypond MWEs but where the essential question still deals with how that program uses LaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not on-topic *per se*, since LilyPond itself is hardly a "related system", more than MathJaX is, for instance. The only exception is when you ask about the interaction between LilyPond and LaTeX, for instance through `lilypond-book`.

---

I have brought the question of where to ask about LilyPond up on [the Big Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) 2 years ago:

[On which site are LilyPond questions on-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168297/on-which-site-are-lilypond-questions-on-topic)

The concensus seems to be that the correct place is either [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). The choice is yours, I would prefer SO for purely technical questions (about LISP/Scheme) and Music for all the other questions.